# MaterialComponents typography opacity

Tags: android, material-design

In `MaterialComponents` theming we can use attributes to either use the default styles or extend them to reflect your design guidelines, e.g.:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextCaption</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="TextCaption" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/inter_regular</item>
    </style>
```

Then the framework automatically applies opacity to the text colors based on the theme, which is kinda cool, because you don't need to handle it manually. For example as far as I know the normal texts in light theme are getting 87%, the caption is getting somewhere around 40%.

But what if I'd like e.g. make the `textAppearanceCaption` have the same opacity as `body1` app-wide without setting the color directly? Is something like this possible? How and when is this opacity applied by the framework? Is it the part of styles?